# IntelliJ IDEA can't setup JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

I'm trying to setup JDK in IntelliJ IDEA and whatever I do, or whatever JDK version I select, nothing happens. The following situation remains:
[image]

So I told IDEA what JDK it should use, but it still asks me to setup a JDK. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Can I apply any workaround to make everything work as usual?

### ADDITION

The steps which I go through setting up the JDK:
situation before setting up:
[image]

the first step:
[image]

the second step:
[image]

the third step:
[image]

the situation after setting up JDK:
[image]

SDKs:
[image]

module settings:
[image]

Comment: How did you tell Intellij? Add some snapshots.

Comment: @yair, thanks for response, added the way how I setup a jdk for the project.

Comment: Make a snapshot from "Project Structur" -> "Plattform Settings" -> SDKs

Comment: @Alex, updated. Thanks for response.

Comment: Make a snapshot of your "Module Settings"

Comment: @Alex, updated, not sure if it is the snapshot of the screen you wanted. Thanks for patience.

Comment: hm, does these locks near the jar picks mean anything? I bet I've never seen it before.

Comment: you have several junit versions in the modul, remove the unused and check your dependencies carfully, I think the problem are missing libraries.

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure, that this is the problem. I removed ALL dependences, and onle JDK left, but idea still doesn't see this, and eclipse works with this jdk just great. It just makes me cry to see such a bugs in such a great IDE, as Intellij idea. Still waiting if somebody has an answer. p.s. even tried to reinstall intellij idea, it didn't help.

Comment: Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`.

Comment: what's your IntelliJ version?

Comment: mother of god, @CrazyCoder, thanks for this, it fixed the problem!!! Please submit it as an answer. I think other people can have problems with this as well.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`File` | `Invalidate Caches` is the first thing you should try in case of such issues.

Comment: You're a life-saver... I thought I broke the IDE! Computer got knocked out by a power blink outage and then I load it back up to all the red errors. Thank you for this @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 6):

Select your modul in the "Project View" and press F4 in the "Project Setting"select "Module".
In the "Module Settings" overview you can add/remove the Modul SDK.

Comment: I tried to delete all jdks and to setup it from scratch, but unfortunately no effect.(

Answer (score 3):

Following this worked for me :

Select your module in Project View

Press F4

Go to SDK

Select you SDK

Make sure you have various jars in there. Else, select proper directory.

In my case, even though correct directory was selected classpath,sourcepath etc were empty.

So I had to select jdk installation directory one more time, which loaded all the jars and solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I followed below steps

1. Press F4
2. Select Modules in Project Settings
3. Set up Module SDK from the drop down or add the new one.
4. Apply & OK

Answer (score 1):

In my case just `File | Invalidate Caches` and `Restart` did not work. Upon Right clicking the project and going to `Module Settings` , I had no SDK selected under `Project Settings->Project`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone like me, looking for a way to setup an offline documentation in IDEA on UBUNTU Linux. You should install the openjdk-8-doc (or openjdk-X-doc in general case) package, then go to `File`|`Project Structure`|`SDKs`|`1.8`(still `1.X` in general), then select tab `Documentation Paths` and add the path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/docs/api` there.

Note, that path of Java docs installation may differ on your machine. You are able to check the path of Java docs installation executing `dpkg-query -L openjdk-8-doc | less` in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this exception in the console:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/remote/RemoteSdkConnectionAcceptor
```

which was caused by the python community edition plugin on Intellij IDEA 2016.2.5.

After updateing/disableing the plugin, I was able to setup the SDK again.