# IntelliJ IDEA and kendo cannot resolve taglib

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kendo-ui, pom.xml

When I use:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
```

I have an error:

```
Cannot resolve taglib with uri http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags
```

With previous version I don't have such problem.

Attempts to add jar to a Project Configuration in IDEA as dependencies
and adding in pom as dependencies doesn't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kendoui</groupId>
    <artifactId>kendo-taglib</artifactId>
    <version>2018.3.911</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>
        ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/kendo-taglib-2018.3.911.jar
    </systemPath>
</dependency>
```

---

```
<%@ taglib prefix=“kendo” uri=“http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags”%>
<%@ taglib prefix=“c” uri=“http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core” %>
```

Comment: Do you see this jar in [list of dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html) of the module? Does it help to change scope to `compile`? The error is usually reported when there is no such taglib jar in the module's classpath (dependencies list).

Comment: Yes, i see this jar. Scope already is compile. I now, and as i wrote with previous version all work fine.

Comment: [This answer help to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147946/7933872)