# JetBrains Rider "Document has exceeded the threshold" error

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider 2018.1.3 on Win 10 x64 to develop some Unity games.

One of my C# scripts is around 12000 lines of code and the file size is about 550KB. Code inspection is disabled for this file, and adding code to this file is getting really hard, because it does not even show the errors to me. I have to type my code, save, go to unity, wait for compile to complete, and see my errors in unity console. The inspection is working fine on small files.

Is there anything I can do to re-enable this feature for large files?

Here is the image of the error I am getting:

[image]

- I have tried reinstalling Rider
- I have tried all the solutions in the following links, unfortunately none of them worked:

  - https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000137704-No-analysis-has-been-performed-Document-size-has-exceeded-the-threshold-
  - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-file-size-limit.html?_ga=2.98728349.2055830657.1567927810-1008993667.1564211256
  - [File size exceeds configured limit (2560000), code insight features not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057988/file-size-exceeds-configured-limit-2560000-code-insight-features-not-availabl)
  - https://medium.com/@yobi.kim/intellij-file-size-exceeds-configured-limit-2560000-code-insight-features-not-available-8ccaae1f2d32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor this file to not be insane.

If there are more than one class in this file - split it up so that it's one file per class.

If it's some gigantic class, then use [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-method) to split it up into logical chunks.

I don't think there is an IDE in the world that would be able to read that file in a helpful manner, so I'm afraid you're just going to have to do some cleaning. Reinstalling Rider or changing settings won't help - you've hit (and probably well exceeded) a hard limit. Even if you could change a setting to 'fix' it, you'll be a lot better off in the long term if you split this up.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The file is just 1 class named Service. it has over 100 methods that calls network APIs and processes the response. It is going to be part of an SDK. other devs are going to use this class by calling different methods of the class like _service.getOnlineUsers(), or _service.getGameHighScore, etc. so i cannot split it. this class was originally coded in java, and i was asked to rewrite it in c# for unity. the java class is much bigger (over 20000 lines of code), but in Intellij IDEA community version, the code inspector is doing fine. I wonder why that is.

Comment: also the same class works fine in visual studio 2019. but since i`m from a java background myself, i am more comfortable with intellij than visual studio.

Comment: The community versions of jetbrains IDEs tend to do much less introspection than the pro version, so that might be why. And imagine how big, say, the unity SDK would be if they shipped it as one file. Don't do this. If it worries you, then ship the compiled dll.

Comment: This is a ridiculous answer.  The issue that JetBrains added some constraint that should be configurable.  My computer is more than powerful enough for VS\ReSharper to be able to process a 100K line file let alone a 10K line file.  The length in lines or bytes shouldn't really determine how much memory or CPU is needed for this, rather the number of variables\properties\methods in the file.  
How does splitting a class into chunks make it more manageable for  the IDE?  It needs to read all chunks and combine them together to be able to process each chunk correctly.

Comment: @Ezra that's a design decision jetbrains has made. You are shooting the messenger here. This answer is correct, regardless of whether you like it. If you want to raise a feature request with jetbrains then by all means, but ranting at somebody trying to help is not productive.

Comment: Sorry @Shadow, you are correct that my main issue is with JetBrains, and your suggestions \ workarounds are appropriate.  But you were asking for it (the "messenger being shot") with your comments: 'not be insane',  'I don't think there is an IDE in the world', 'have to do some cleaning' - you could have just said that its a design decision jetbrains has made without attacking the OP (or anyone who has a large class in a single file).