# IntelliJ Idea Cannot resolve imported jar at kotlin projec

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, editor

I create kotlin project at this link https://github.com/davidasync/dismember-pedia and use `gradle installDist` to create .jar file.
And I copy paste the jar file at https://github.com/davidasync/aetherlens `libs` folder

I don't know why, the editor cannot resolve the word `dismemberPedia`, although i can run it. It seems the intelij idea cannot resolve and detect the jar

[image]

I already this below solutions but no one works,

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Refresh all gradle project
- Rebuild project
- Try this solution [Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import)

Comment: Does your jar contain the Kotlin runtime? If so, then it's a known problem with jars compiled with Kotlin 1.2.50+: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25709

Comment: Yes, its kotlin code, 
I see, so that's known issue, thanks for the answer