# Intellij cannot import class

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, import

I added dependency to my pom file. I see that it was added to the dependency tree. In the class Idea proposes to import the class I need but when I press alt+enter nothing happens, it just proposes to import again. 
[image]

[image]
I tried all the solutions mentioned here: [Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import)
(invalidate cache, maven reimport, checked source and dependency folders, everything). Nothing helped. 
I use Intellij Idea 2019.2 Ultimate edition.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after failed import?

Comment: Reindex your pom.  Make sure the updated JAR appears in your local .m2 repository.  If that still doesn't work, remove the JAR from your local .m2 and reimport.

Comment: @y.bedrov    Looks like no. I cleared the log,  clicked maven - reimport. And all I see is:
`2019-09-09 17:11:03,324 [5691817]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-09-09 17:11:03,436 [5691929]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 42ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-09-09 17:11:03,565 [5692058]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 128ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
`

Comment: Do you face the same issue with new sample project?