# Java can't create Connection object

Tags: java, database, connection

This is the first time I'm connecting to a database so I am sorry if it's a stupid question but I am trying to follow tutorial or something but every one already starts where creating a Connection object is possible while I can't create it. IntelliJ doesn't recognize it and I can't import anything specific related to sql.

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you importing the package?  Try adding "import java.sql.Connection" to the file.

Comment: no, just this, https://i.imgur.com/YdwHeNO.png

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your IDE.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078

Comment: So since I am on macOS, Mac M1, I had to use Java 16 in order to have functional JavaFX. When I try to create a normal project on Java 17 I can import Connection, Driver manager etc. but then JavaFX won't work :/

Comment: you need to add a * to that.  but you should import only Connection since that's what you're using.