# How to access inner class elements in scala

Tags: scala

I have a simple inner class variable, how do i access it in scala?

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    var x = 1
  }}


object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val o = new Outer
    val i = new o.Inner
    println(i.x)
  }
}
```

The problem is that IntelliJ complains that it cannot resolve x, but when i run the program it works fine.[image]

Comment: what's wrong with println(i.x)? Works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can simply use `.member_name` to access variables in scala.**

```
scala> class Outer {
        class Inner {
          var x = 1 //it can be val which is immutable
        }}
defined class Outer

scala> val o = new Outer
o: Outer = Outer@358b0b42

scala> val i = new o.Inner
i: o.Inner = Outer$Inner@512f2c7d

scala> i.x
res13: Int = 1
```

since your example has x defined as mutable, you can change the value of `x`,

```
scala> i.x = 100
i.x: Int = 100

scala> i.x
res14: Int = 100
```

See working example - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/C9k9an4ASdaISnohbYQBmA

**If you don't really need Outer to be a class, you can define it as singleton,**

```
scala> object Outer {
     |             class Inner {
     |               var x = 1 //it can be val which is immutable
     |             }}
defined object Outer
```

then, simple instantiate Inner and access variables,

```
scala> val inner = new Outer.Inner
inner: Outer.Inner = Outer$Inner@4bcdd11

scala> inner.x
res2: Int = 1
```

**Regarding not working on intellij,** [File | Invalidate Caches/Restart...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632676/432903) should work

Comment: This is simple, but can you please explain why this does not work in IntelliJ, thanks

Comment: The example is obviously working example. Try REPL which helps learning small stuffs in scala. What error you get in intellij? or What does intellij display x to be. update your question

Comment: in your example you are printing `i`, not `i.x`

Comment: Ok, this seems very odd, if i try println(i.x) the x is marked in red and IntelliJ says "cannot resolve symbol". But when I run the program, it works fine.

Comment: Run working code here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/C9k9an4ASdaISnohbYQBmA. Can you post the screenshot in question?

Comment: I have added the snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: I tried in intellij17 too, it does work for me. what your scala setup look like in intellij? I bet intellij is freaked out. Try [`File | Invalidate Caches/Restart...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/432903). Also try running even with error.

Comment: Thanks it works file after I invalidated Caches/restart. I can see the variable

Comment: Awesome. Intellij is trash sometimes.