# IntelliJ IDEA Java Maven `The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved`

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

#### Upon `IntelliJ IDEA > File > New > Project from Existing Sources... > Import project from external model > Maven`, I can't successfully `mvn compile`.

Instead Maven fails that with..

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
...
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

.. on seemingly *every* classtype (not just `Object` as above) in the project.

**How can I configure my IntelliJ to successfully `mvn compile`?**

---

*[Questions that are similar to this, but not exactly the same (although maybe tangentially helpful)]:*

- [Why so red? IntelliJ seems to think every declaration/method cannot be found/resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632120/why-so-red-intellij-seems-to-think-every-declaration-method-cannot-be-found-res?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  - Nothing is red in my IntelliJ IDEA
- [Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import)

  - Sounds like the wording of that [error?], "Cannot resolve symbol on import", is similar but different from mine ("The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files")
  - A text search of that page also [CMD+F / Ctrl+F], for parts of my specific Error message {"cannot be resolved", "indirectly referenced", ".class"}, shows no matches - which further leads me to think that Question is slightly different
  - Question itself makes no mention of `Maven`

Answer (score 0):

**Make `Project` SDK *match* `Module` SDK**

*I happened to have a mismatch of configured SDK...*

1. `Project window > right-click your [Maven] Project > Open Module Settings > Project Settings`
2. Set these to match on their `SDK` (and maybe also `Language level`):

   - `Project > SDK`
   - `Modules > Dependencies > Module SDK`
3. Now try to `mvn compile` again